# Splash Screen not functioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, splash-screen

I am trying to make a splash screen that disappears after 4 seconds. I am trying to do this by adding the `display-none` class to the `splash` class through JS, but the class is not being added, so the splash screen is still being displayed. Here is the codepen of the issue:

https://codepen.io/dbake3452/pen/VwmeoGa

```
///HTML

<div class="splash">
      <img class="fade-in" src="images/pippinhop.png">
</div>


///SASS

.splash {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #a9aaff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    .display-none {
        display: none;
    };

    img {
        width: 12.5%;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn{
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.fade-in {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in forwards;
}



///JS

const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
setTimeout(() => {
splash.classList.add('display-none');
 }, 4000);
});'
```

Answer (score 2):

the issue is all about your css definition.

```
.splash {
    .display-none {}
}
```

This css style means, find element with the class of `.splash` then find it's children which has `.display-none` class and style it according to the style definition. You may want to change the `SASS` code to this, making it a global style solves the problem:

```
.display-none {
    display: none;
}
.splash {
...
```

or you have one option to make it `.splash.display-none` with `&` keyword as shown here:

```
.splash {
/* Your style...*/
    &.display-none {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

The `&.classname2` in .classname1 equals to the `.classname1.classname2` css syntax.

Here is an example:

```
.classname1 {
    &.classname2 {
    /*style...*/
    }
}
```

in css you'd write this:

```css
.classname1.classname2 {
    /*style...*/
}
```

And this can be described as "find the elements which has the `.classname1` and `.classname2`, and style accordingly".

I hope this helps! :D

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your Codepen it appears that your JS is fine because I do see the class being added. If you remove the semicolon from after the "display-none" class, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The way the SCSS is written it is rendering the CSS as

```
.splash .display-none {
  display: none;
}
```

The space between the two selectors is significant.

> The descendant combinator — typically represented by a single space (
> ) character — combines two selectors such that elements matched by the
> second selector are selected if they have an ancestor (parent,
> parent's parent, parent's parent's parent, etc) element matching the
> first selector. Selectors that utilize a descendant combinator are
> called descendant selectors.

(from `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator`) so, as others have pointed out, you need to separate out the definition of the display-none class. The rendered CSS needs to look like this:

```
.splash.display-none {
  display: none;
}
```